# Jhipster microservices REST api retry

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, spring-cloud, jhipster, azure-aks

I am using Jhipster to create gateway and microservices. These are deployed on Azure Kubernetes cluster.

I noticed that sometimes an API can take more than 60 seconds. In such cases, this API is automatically retried. Even when i call the api simply hitting browser, internally api gets called multiple times.
I am not sure if I have to tweak any settings in gateway or should that be in AKS.

Can someone help?

Regards,

Venky